# I am making a class in python that would add two numbers then print if its enough or not but It doesn't add?

Tags: python, class, oop, input, conditional-statements

#this is my code that would add loaned and withdrawed but it seems like my code is wrong but it doesn't have

```
class Money:
    loaned = 0
    withdrawed = 0
    totalMoney = 0

    def bankMoney (self):
        self.totalMoney = self.withdrawed + self.loaned
            return totalMoney
        if totalMoney >= 1000000:
            print(" enough money,")
        else: 
            print("not enough")

m1 = Money()
m1.loaned = float(input("loaned"))
m1.withdrawed = float(input("withdrawed"))
```

#then when I try to execute it. it just ask the user but doesn't solve

Comment: you need to call the function `bankMoney()` to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the return statement if you want the print statements inside the method `bankMoney`, as statements after return are not executed.
2. Add `self.` to `totalMoney` at the if statement
3. Call the method `m1.bankMoney` to execute it

Try the following:
**Code**

```
class Money:
    loaned = 0
    withdrawed = 0
    totalMoney = 0

    def bankMoney (self):
        self.totalMoney = self.withdrawed + self.loaned
        if self.totalMoney >= 1000000:
            print(" enough money,")
        else:
            print("not enough")

m1 = Money()
m1.loaned = float(input("loaned "))
m1.withdrawed = float(input("withdrawed "))
m1.bankMoney()
```

**Output**

```
loaned 1000000
withdrawed 1
 enough money,
```

Comment: thank you. I am always failing to see this kind of mistake.

Comment: @Beginnertoeverything it happens to everyone, keep practicing!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
class Money():
    def __init__(self,l, w):
        self.loaned = l
        self.withdrawed = w
        self.totalMoney = 0
    def bankMoney(self):
        self.totalMoney = self.withdrawed + self.loaned
        if self.totalMoney >= 1000000:
            print("enough money,")
        else: 
            print("not enough")
        return self.totalMoney # this is returned at the end

loaned = float(input("loaned : "))
withdrawed = float(input("withdrawed: "))
m1 = Money(loaned, withdrawed)
print(m1.bankMoney()) # the method within the class is to be called.
```

Output:

```
loaned : 555.4444
withdrawed: 654654653545.89
enough money,
654654654101.3345
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues:

1. the function is not executed
2. your return statement is not indented correctly
3. you can't return before print, then you won't be able to execute the print statement at all

try it:

```
class Money:
    def __init__(self):
        self.totalMoney = 1000000
        self.loaned = float(input("loaned: "))
        self.withdrawed =  float(input("withdrawed: "))

    def bankMoney (self):
        total = self.withdrawed + self.loaned
        if total >= self.totalMoney:
            print(" enough money")
        else:
            print("not enough")
        return total


m1 = Money()
m1.bankMoney()
```